# How to parse a json object in the value

Tags: logstash, filebeat

I have record in log file with records in JSON:

```
{"created":1610314252.6277733,"process":13,"levelname":"INFO","message":"Requesting url: http://smshost:8080/push with method: POST and params {'data': {'message': 'Record changed: go to:XXXX', 'resource_id': '1824908f-efae-474e-aa3e-579cabe67517', 'subscriber': '000000000000', 'service': 'SERVICE'}, 'json': None}","message_id":268562185}
```

Filebeat send this data to logstash

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- paths:
   - /opt/apps/mobilizer/*.log
  input_type: log
  json.keys_under_root: true
  json.add_error_key: true
  json.message_key: log
```

Output data:

```
{
    "@timestamp":"2021-01-11T09:53:48.062Z",
    "@metadata":{"beat":"filebeat","type":"doc","version":"6.8.13"},
    "levelname":"INFO",
    "source":"/opt/apps/mobilizer/logs/test.json",
    "offset":114,
    "message":"Requesting url: http://smshost:8080/push with method: POST and params {'data': {'message': 'Record changed: go to:XXXX', 'resource_id': '1824908f-efae-474e-aa3e-579cabe67517', 'subscriber': '000000000000', 'service': 'SERVICE'}, 'json': None}",
    "beat":{"name":"skif-HP-240-G7-Notebook-PC","hostname":"skif-HP-240-G7-Notebook-PC","version":"6.8.13"},
    "host":{"name":"skif-HP-240-G7-Notebook-PC"},
    "message_id":268562185,
    "error":{"message":"Key 'log' not found","type":"json"},
    "log":{"file":{"path":"/opt/apps/mobilizer/logs/test.json"}},
    "process":13,"created":1.6103142526277733e+09
}
```

But I want to parse the "message" and get the dictionary data after "paran". (Either in logstash or filebeat ):

```
{
    ...
    "message":"Requesting url: http://smshost:8080/push with method: POST and params ",
    "data": {"message": "Record changed: go to:XXXX", "resource_id": "1824908f-efae-474e-aa3e-579cabe67517', "subscriber": "000000000000', "service": "SERVICE"}, 
    "json": "None",
    ...
}
```

How can I do this? Where is it better to do in logstash or in filebeat?

Comment: in logstash: [grok filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) with this pattern: `and params %{GREEDYDATA:to_parse}` on the message field. Then [json filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html) on the to_parse field. I don't have time to test it, but that should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But if json data change this filter not work fine :(